# How to use refresh tokens in jwt authentication

Tags: authentication, jwt, refresh-token

I have some questions about implementing refresh tokens. I searched a lot but found nothing :

1. Do I have to use `jwt` for Refresh Token or it can be a hashed string? What are the benefits of using `jwt` in Refresh Tokens?
2. Should Refresh Tokens have an expiration time? I want to use Refresh Tokens for `remember me` feature, so if the user comes back to the website or mobile app after a month, he should be able to continue as a logged in user.
3. Do I have to send Refresh Token to client? (As we store it in database and we delete it in logout)

Answer (score 2):

I am using JWT token for refresh purposes. It has different claims as access token. Additionally I am storing some `refreshKey` claim which is also stored in database. This approach allows me to revoke this token just in case(for example user blockage functionality).

1. Benefits : You have the same validation mechanism as for access token (validity check, expiration date etc).
2. Usually refresh tokens has very long expiration time (way longer then access token). Using long access tokens is not recommended, as you are not able to revoke them. It is fine to have long lasting refresh token as long as you can revoke them.
3. Yes you have to send it to client, to keep you architecture stateless (I suppose this is your purpose of using JWT)

Comment: `Yes you have to send it to client, to keep you architecture stateless` : Refresh tokens must be saved in the database. So we can handle logout feature. So your sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: And as we must save refresh token in database, we don't need to validate them, so we don't have to use `jwt` in refresh token. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can save only one claim from refresh token in database, not the whole token.  `{
  iss: "iss value",
  aud: "aud value",
  exp: 1553521788,
  refreshKey: "key stored in db"
}`

Comment: My question is exactly here, why we do not just send `refreshKey` to the user? Why do we need to verify it (as jwt)? We can save `refreshKey` in db, send it to the user, and delete from db when the user wants to log out.

Comment: I think the only reason is when we want to log out the user, we can determine which Refresh Token must be deleted from the database. (Because, user could be able to login from multiple device and can log out from each one when he want)

Comment: I think your approach is also ok. The only problem is the validity of this refresh token. If you going to control it you have to store additionally expiration date in db.

Comment: Why should we set expiry date for Refresh Token? What should we do if it expires? (We want to keep user signed in for always, when he check "remember me")

Comment: Sorry, I am maybe a little bit too boxed:) I have used the approach, that if user does not use an application for a month, he is logged out. But if you wan't keep him logged in forever you don't need expiring refresh tokens.

Comment: Thanks, and finally I don't need to make my Refresh Key a `jwt` anymore. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks for your support. If you want to edit your answer according to our discussion, I would accept it as true answer. Btw, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Refresh token is to be used by the client to acquire a new access token from the server. So, the format of the refresh token is completely upto the authorization server that issues token. If you are issuing 'Access Token' and 'Refresh Token' then it is easier to have the same format i.e. JWT format.
2. Refresh tokens must have expiry time. It can be much longer than regular access token expiry time. It can always be made configurable by the resource.
3. You should send the refresh token to the client so that the client can use it to request a new token.